# SendMessage always returns zero

Tags: c#, user32

I am using the User32 `SendMessage` function to send raw keyboard input to my API.

The function that intercepts the `SendMessage` call is the `WndProc` function. I need to receive this data back where `SendMessage` was called from. I have tried setting the `message.Result` and saving the `SendMessage` function to an int, but every time it equals 0. How can I obtain this return data?

**Calling the Function**

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint wMsg, int wParam, ref Rawkeyboard lParam);

public void SomeFunction(...){
   int result = SendMessage(Hook, 0x1230FF, 0, ref lParamKeyboard).ToInt32(); // Send data
   Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

**Responding to the call**

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message message){
    switch (message.Msg){
         case 0x1230FF: {
             message.Result = (IntPtr)6; // Set result as 6 (just for testing)
         }
         break;
     }
     base.WndProc(ref message);
}
```

Comment: After you set `message.Result`, you then call `base.WndProc(ref message)` which will modify the message further. Also, window message numbers go up to 65535. 0x1230ff is out of range.

Comment: @RaymondChen I have changed the message number to `0x00FF` as well as not executing `base.WndProc(ref message)` if the case is my message, still not working ;( any other suggestions?

Comment: Message `0x00FF` is already defined by the system as `WM_INPUT`. Class custom messages must be in the range `0x0400` to `0x7FFF`. App custom messages must be in the range `0x8000` to `0xBFFF`.

Comment: This isn't broken.  Simplest explanation is that you used the wrong window handle.  Start VS a second time and use it to debug the app with the WndProc call.  Set a breakpoint to verify that code actually runs.